# Automatically save Spotify's Discover Weekly Playlists

Tags: spotify

Spotify's new Discover Weekly feature kind of killed it this week so I'd be keen to set up a script of some description to autosave the playlist every Tuesday. First, is this possible with either the AppleScript or the Web API? And second, what docs would get me started?

Comment: I think the user would have to add this new playlist , then get the id of this new playlist you are talking about , then just get the playlist like you would any other

Comment: Hmmmm it's an auto generated playlist from Spotify that refreshes every Monday. I'll check the ID next week but I assume it remains the same. The issue is the contents change. So whatever solution just needs to create a copy of the playlist so there's a non-dynamic one.

Comment: if you have the id of the playlist , then just look up api docs , getting contents of a playlist is one of the easiest things to do , save it where ever you want .  Make a new folder each week and save the playlist from that week.  Sounds pretty easy

Answer (score 4):

This is a great idea, and the [Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api) has the functionality you need to build this. (AppleScript doesn't.)

Firstly, you should read through the [Authorization Guide](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/) since you'll need an access token when making your requests. You'll find that there are three *flows*, and which one you pick depends a bit on how your application is going to work.

**How do you find a user's Discover Weekly playlist?**

The Discover Weekly playlist's URI has the format `spotify:user:spotifydiscover:playlist:{id}`, and is saved by default at the top of the user's list of playlists. You can retrieve this list using the [Get a List of a User's Playlists endpoint](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-list-users-playlists/). **However** - There's absolutely no guarantee that this playlist is the user's Discover Weekly playlist. It may be that the user has followed another user's Discover Weekly playlist and might even have unfollowed their own Discover Weekly. **Also** - Note that the Discover Weekly playlists are `private` by default, meaning that you *have* to get the user's permission to have it included in the list of their playlists. Read more about permissions in the [Using Scopes section](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/using-scopes/) on the Developer site.

**The user gives your application their Discover Weekly playlist**

The most simple case I can imagine is that you let the user tell your application which Playlist to start storing. You could do this by either allowing the user to input the Playlist's URI directly, or to again use the Get a List of User's Playlists endpoint to give the user some playlists to choose from. (Filter out all playlists that isn't called *Discover Weekly* and is owned by the user `spotifydiscover`).

I don't really want to get into the [Terms of Use](https://developer.spotify.com/developer-terms-of-use/) here, but please have a read through them to make sure your application doesn't break them.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

On the Spotify Idea Exchange, [it has been suggested to the Spotify team](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Live-Ideas/Discover-View-previous-Discover-Weekly-playlists/idi-p/1178081) that they create a way for users to view / access previous Discover Weekly playlists.  If that idea gets enough support *("kudos")*, their dev team may consider it for inclusion into the official client's functionality.

In the meantime, a user on that same thread has created **[an IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/recipes/311873-discover-weekly-archive) which will "automatically add the new 30 tracks on the Discover Weekly playlist recommended by Spotify each Monday morning to a personal Discover Weekly Archive playlist, so they will not get lost."**  So, if you're willing to get an IFTTT account and give it access to your Spotify account, that should be a workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small docker image which can be run every week. It will save your playlist to your playlists under the name 'DiscoverWeekly_[Year]_[CalendarWeek], e.g. 'DiscoverWeekly_2015_43'.

Repo and instructions on how to run it:
https://github.com/matlockx/spotify-playlist

Comment: Clever way to avoid picking a date string format.  Why calendar with a 'K', though?

Comment: Ups... It's German for calendar. Will change :)